# How one can show that this seven degree polynomial has no real roots in $(0,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, roots

How one can show that this seven degree polynomial has no real roots in the interval $(0,1)$:
$$z^7+20z^6-z^5-576=0.$$
I have no idea to start

Comment: The polynomial has odd degree in the most-significant term, and therefore there must be a sign change somewhere, which means there must be at least one real zero, i.e., at least one real root.

Comment: general method is using [Sturm's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem)

Comment: Decartes' rule of signs implies that since there is one sign change in the coefficients, there is *exactly* one positive root.

Comment: with Maple i have found three real solutions

Comment: your statement is not true.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: I have edited the question

Comment: Descartes rule of signs gives one positive real root and at most 6 negative real roots.

Comment: For $z \in [0,1]$, the polynomial is bounded from above by
$$1^7+20\cdot 1^6−164\cdot 0^5−1696 \cdot 0^4−4432\cdot 0^3−3968\cdot 0^2−896\cdot 0−576 = -555$$

Comment: Any good reason why you changed the polynomial *after* the question was answered (and accepted)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Over the interval $(0,1)$ the first two terms of the polynomial $z^7 + 20 z^6$ assume values in the interval $(0,21)$.  Adding the constant term $-576$ to any value in this interval always yields a negative number. And all of the other terms also assume negative values over $(0,1)$.  Therefore the polynomial as a whole assumes only negative values over $(0,1)$.  As others said, without a sign change in the interval, there is no root.

Comment: The same thing, in a clearer mathematical statement: for $z \in (0,1)$ we have $z^7 + 20 z^6 \le 1^7 + 20 \cdot 1^6 = 21 \color{red} < 576 \le 576 + z^5$, therefore $z^7 + 20z^6 - z^5 - 576 < 0$, so there is no root in the prescribed interval.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to show that $f$ is increasing on $[0,1]$; furthermore $f(0)=-576$ and $f(1)=-556$.

Comment: I suppose $f(z)=z^7+20z^6-z^5-576$. I also suppose you computed $f'(z)=z^4(7z^2+120z-5)$ and noticed that $f'(\frac{1}{120})<0$. In other words, the sign of $f'$ is given by $7z^2+120z-5$ which isn't positive on $[0,1]$.